# Canvas, remove overlapping lines

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create a custom shape generator. I'm using the canvas to draw shapes from trapezoid.

I actually have a good result :

[First trapezoid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Aejr.png)

[Second trapezoid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBubQ.png)

Code behind :

```
const drawPolygon = (info, index) => {
  const { l1, l2, h } = info;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(originX, originY);
  ctx.lineTo(originX + l1 / 2, originY);
  ctx.lineTo(originX + l2 / 2, originY + h);
  ctx.lineTo(originX - l2 / 2, originY + h);
  ctx.lineTo(originX - l1 / 2, originY);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  originY = originY + h;
};
```

Where info is coming from an array of data : `[{ l1: 200, l2: 200, h: 50 }];`

The drawing process is working fine, but i'd like to automatically hide the overlapping lines, or even better merge the shapes to achieve something like that :
[I shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8TFL.png)

And actually I have :
[I shape from generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZAQF.png)

And I want it to look like :
[Hiding lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUNJq.png)

Comment: An idea: mathematically detect the overlapping areas and draw lines on top of them.

Comment: You can give your shape a fill of let’s say white, then the shape drawn second will hide the liens of the shape drawn first.

Comment: But the top line of the second shape will still be diplayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ctx.fill()` instead of `ctx.stroke()` so it looks like the "I shape" you have as an example.

An idea in case you still want to see the paths being drawn is to pass a boolean to your method in case the user wants to see the paths:

```js
const drawPolygon = (info, index, showPaths) => {
  const { l1, l2, h } = info;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(originX, originY);
  ctx.lineTo(originX + l1 / 2, originY);
  ctx.lineTo(originX + l2 / 2, originY + h);
  ctx.lineTo(originX - l2 / 2, originY + h);
  ctx.lineTo(originX - l1 / 2, originY);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  if (showPaths) ctx.stroke();
  originY = originY + h;
};
```

For the color, check out `ctx.fillStyle = #2c93b0` and the path color: `ctx.strokeStyle = #CCC`.

The `showPaths` parameter could potentially be a checkbox in your interface.

Comment: Thank you, I think that will do for what I need !